# How does PHP syntax <?=$var;?> work?

Tags: php, syntax

I recently discovered some code that output a variable in php like this:

```
<?=$var;?>
```

I have never seen this before. Is it the same as

```
<?php echo $var;?>
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?=$var;?>
```

is the same as

```
<?php echo $var;?>
```

But it will only work if you have:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in your php.ini

As of php 5.4 short_open_tag isn't required. The shorthand version is always available. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

@jszobody: Thanks for your comment!

Comment: As of php 5.4 short_open_tag isn't required. The shorthand version is always available. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag